# Consumir XML con web service usando Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, webservice

Estoy comenzando mi proyecto de tesis y salió este tema nuevo para mi. Los web services.
Básicamente, necesito construir un web service en laravel, que me permita trabajar unos archivos xml que me enviará SAP y que contienen la info de vehículos que van entrando a taller.

El xml es el siguiente:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrdenIngreso xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<NumeroPedido>0201932214</NumeroPedido>
<Patente>JP-JP97</Patente>
<Chasis>WDDBF4DB5XX510012</Chasis>
<FechaEntrega>201XX426</FechaEntrega>
<RutAsesor>96682XX-1</RutAsesor>
<NombreAsesor>Chris Allikson Maturana Santander</NombreAsesor>
<CodigoCanal>34</CodigoCanal>
<CodigoMarca>01</CodigoMarca>
<DescripcionMarca>Mercedes-Benz</DescripcionMarca>
<CodigoModelo>176043A</CodigoModelo>
<DescripcionModelo>A 200</DescripcionModelo>
<CodigoCiaSeguro>0001017074</CodigoCiaSeguro>
<DescripcionCiaSeguro>CHILENA CONSOLIDADA SEGUROS GENERAL</DescripcionCiaSeguro>
<Cliente>KAUFMANN S.A. VEHICULOS MOTORIZADOS</Cliente>
<CodigoColor>191</CodigoColor>
<DescripcionColor>NEGRO COSMOS</DescripcionColor>
<TipoPedido>ZS12</TipoPedido>
<DescripcionTipoPedido>OT aseguradora</DescripcionTipoPedido>
<CodigoSucursal>1181</CodigoSucursal>
<DescripcionSucursal>Sucursal Santiago</DescripcionSucursal>
</OrdenIngreso>
```

Una vez recibido, ya tengo que ver como lo trabajo, para guardar esta info en base de datos en caso de que no exista.

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.8 y mysql

Desde ya cualquier comentario, bienvenido y gracias.

Comment: Francisco, pudiste solucionarlo? estoy atascado con esto y no he encontrado la solución. Solo me ha funcionado en php puro, pero no en Laravel. Si pudiste, favor de agregar tu solución. Por mientras seguiré investigando. Gracias!

Comment: Hola @rbarrera ... no no pude..solucionarlo por tiempo mas que nada. Finalmente con REST y postman hice una simulación de como se inyectarian los datos a mi sistema. Suerte en tu investigacion amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola como estas Francisco te mostrare como leo yo los archivos XML con laravel, tomando en cuenta que esos xml serán standard:

1. Primero debes guardar el archivo en el disco local storage/vehiculos (por ejemplo)
2. Luego cargas **DOMDocument** como el ejemplo abajo

   $dom = new DOMDocument;
     $dom->load("ruta donde esta el archivo". "nombre del archivo" . '.xml');
3. una vez ya cargado el archivo lo tienes en **$dom** y puedes sacar elemento por elemento.

   $NumeroPedido = $dom->getElementsByTagName("NumeroPedido")[0];
   $Patente = $dom->getElementsByTagName("Patente")[0];
4. Luego ya lo guardas en la base de datos que crees para almacenar la información

   Vehicules::create(['numero_pedido'=>$numeroPedido->nodeValue,'patente'=>$Patente->nodeValue]);

Me parece que con eso puedes hacer lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias @Anwar Sarmiento. 
Con Guzzle, logré hacer el cliente.,  pero no consiguo hacer el WDSL, estoy atascado en eso aun. Viendo videos, github,,, pero me cuesta adaptar lo que está en internet que está en base a php puro,,,, y no orientado a frameworks.

Tengo que serguir investigando.
Saludos

Comment: Hola Francisco, lograste hacer el WDSL? cómo continuó tu investigación, sí puedes compartir tu investigación sería de mucha ayuda, saludos.